# Node JS and JWT Encode: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Im attempting to construct a JWT assertion using npm package simple-jwt. The algorithm required for my OAuth2 Request is RS256. Below is the call to the encode method.

```
var claims = {
  'iss': 'veds3i33z1fx6dle7iv3z344zbwy6miv',
  'sub': '54',
  'box_sub_type': 'user',
  'aud': 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token',
  'jti': 'M4yeY3W63TxHa9jFek85',
  'exp': exp
};

var options = {
  header: {
    'kid': '8nkq5s45'
  }
};

var token = jwt.encode(claims, 'fakesecret', 'RS256', options);
```

The stack trace is as follows:

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line at Error (native) at Sign.sign (crypto.js:279:26) at sign (/Users/Aaron/Sites/app.barmehealth.com/auth_api/node_modules/jwt-simple/lib/jwt.js:181:57)

As far as I can tell there is a problem that occurs after the following method call on line 181 of jwt.js:

```
base64str = crypto.createSign(method).update(input).sign(key, 'base64');
```

I cannot find a crypto.js file in the crypto npm package so I have no idea how to debug further. However the method is there when I console the method like so: console.log(crypto.createSign);

Comment: Instead of `fakesecret` you need a private RSA key (in PEM format, I think) to be able to sign the token. `crypto` is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html).